# how to make component don't return until async function complete?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication

i'm trying to create a private route.my idea is check user logged or not in App.jsx and store this state with redux.

```
import {getAuth,onAuthStateChanged} from "firebase/auth"
...
function App() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
 
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    async function stateChanged(){
      await onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
         dispatch(checkState(true))
        } else {
         dispatch(checkState(false))
        }
      });
    }
    stateChanged()
  },[dispatch,auth])
  return (
    <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/login"
      element={<Auth authRoute="login"/> }
    />
    <Route
      path="/details"
      element={<PrivateRoute component={UserDetailsProfile}/>}
    />
    ...
  </Routes>
  );
}
```

in my store, i'll change state based on props that onAuthStateChanged give

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    auth: {
      isLoading: false,
      isAuthenticate: false,
      user: {...User},
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    checkState(state,action){
      if(state.auth.isLoading) state.auth.isLoading = false
      state.auth.isAuthenticate = action.payload
    }
  ...
  },
```

in my PrivateRoute,if user logged, i route to components and navigate to login page if not.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component:Component,...rest}) => {
   
    const {isLoading,isAuthenticate} = useSelector(authSelector)
    if (isLoading)
    return (
        <div className='spinner-container'>
            <Spinner animation='border' variant='info' />
        </div>
    )
    return isAuthenticate ? (<Component/>) :(<Navigate to="/login"/>) 
}
```

but i face a bug, when web reloaded(F5) , all state on store was reset,and PrivateRoute run before onAuthStateChanged method complete,so have anyway for my problem?

thanks for help and have a nice day,everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use redux-persist library to keep loggedIn user info in localStorage.
Something like this:

```
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import userReducer from './userReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['isAuthenticate'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);

const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

<Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistStore(store)}>
        <App />
    </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

Comment: oh thanks so much, i'll use it

Comment: Redux persist works well, but you may want to consider saving state to session storage instead of local storage

Comment: @Bugbeeb Yes, if you want clear the data after close the browser you can use session storage as well